# deploying managed package to scratch org failing giving Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out

Tags: managed-package, deployment, ant-script

Trying to deploy a managed package using ant migration tool getting the above message. Username and password+token from the scratch org are correct. I used the same credentials to test retrieving the dlrs package from scratch org A. I am trying to deploy it to scratch org B. Any ideas how to solve this issue or am I missing something.
As I understand it, there is no need to retrieve any metadata from scratch Org A as a pre-requisite to deploy to scratch org B.

my build.xml

```
<project name="Sample usage of Salesforce Ant tasks" basedir="." xmlns:sf="antlib:com.salesforce">

    <property file="build.properties"/>
    <property environment="env"/>

        <import file="${basedir}/lib/ant-salesforce.xml"/>


    <condition property="sf.username" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.username"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.password" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.password"/> </not> </condition>
    <condition property="sf.sessionId" value=""> <not> <isset property="sf.sessionId"/> </not> </condition>

    <taskdef resource="com/salesforce/antlib.xml" uri="antlib:com.salesforce">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="./lib/ant-salesforce.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <target name="deploydlrs">
        <installPackage namespace="dlrs" version="2.5"
           username="${sf.username}" password="${sf.password}"/>
    </target>
...
</project>
```

when I run ant deploydlrs, it correctly creates the following folder structure

[image]

but then I get this message

```
lib\ant-salesforce.xml:27: Invalid username, password, security token; or user locked out.
```

the salesforce.xml is copied from [Andrew Fawcett](https://andyinthecloud.com/2013/06/23/look-ma-no-hands-automating-install-and-uninstall-of-packages/). Username or password don't have characters that needs escaping.

Comment: Any reason you are not using the sfdx CLI package install command?

Comment: NB: the credentials will be specific to each org, including scratch orgs...

Comment: Good question, I am trying to automate the deployment process via ant. Yes I have two entries in my build.properties, sf.username for orgA and sf.username.orgB. this should be ok and it works when I retrieve

Comment: You can invoke sfdx commands from an ant script if you want to. Just use the [standard CLI execution task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

Comment: I would recommend migrating away from the old Ant tasks Salesforce created. They are now replaced by sfdx, especially in the context of scratch orgs.

Comment: ok, I see, so I can invoke sfdx command from ant script, not sure why I did not think about this earlier. That is cool, I will try it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use the Ant Migration Tool if you can help it. The [sfdx-cli](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli) is much better, as you can simply script:

```
sfdx force:package:install -p dlrs@2.5 -u <desired-scratch-org-alias>
```

You simply need a sfdx-project.json file that includes the alias for it:

```
{ ...
  "packageAliases": {
    "dlrs@2.5": "04t-package-id"
  }
}
```

Also, having previously installed packages using Ant, this blog post includes a custom command, as installPackage isn't part of the core Ant package and takes more work to use. I used to use the deploy script, just specify the InstalledPackage metadata type with the relevant names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>dlrs</members>
    <name>InstalledPackage</name>
  </types>
  <version>51.0</version>
</Package>
```

This technically works, but is very annoying to maintain. The upside, however, is that you can simultaneously install many packages with a single package.xml file (I've installed about 10 packages at once this way).

Comment: just bear with me, you say stay away from ant migration tool, can the sfdx command be automated? if so how would I approach this

Comment: @MoAli Yes, you can use Windows Tasks or crontab, bash/sh/zsh/cmd/PowerShell/etc scripts, CI/CD (Jenkins, etc), and so on with sfdx cli. Also, it requires Node, but notably does not require Java in order to run, which makes it far more lightweight overall.

Comment: this and the comment from @PhilW are the right answers. thanks

Comment: We have Ant scripting that invokes sfdx, and we also have yaml scripting that does the same. One of the benefits of both is OS portability.

Comment: @PhilW Good point. I'm mostly concerned about the Ant Migration Tool specifically. It's a relatively fickle piece of code that can be really obtuse to do pretty much anything.

Comment: @PhilW and sfdcfox well a good start for me, gulp tasks, came to the rescue. that is currently working although I am having other issues such as sfdx push standard objects but that is another question to ask at some point later.